# truncating number after decimal...through built in function in java

Tags: java

i want to truncate a number after decimal through a  **built in function in** **java** (not javascript). 
**for example:**
69.80000000001  to  69.8

please guide.

Comment: Truncate / Round have the unfortunate property that they cannot produce the number 69.8 as output.  They'll probably give you 69.7999999999999971578290569595992565155029296875, which is close.

Comment: truncate noy round off. because i want 69.8001 into 69.8 not into 70.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about the [Decimal Format](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) class?

<s>I haven't tested this, but:</s> Okay, this *should* work:

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.math.RoundingMode;
public class Test
{
   public static void main(String args[])
   {
        double i = 69.8999999999;
        DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat("#.#"); 
        format.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.FLOOR);
        String s = format.format(i);
        i = Double.parseDouble(s);
        System.out.println(i); //should be 69.8
   }
}
```

Comment: it is not running in JCreator (java programing enviorment). should I include any header file? or something else.

Comment: There are a couple of import statements required. I've edited my original answer, I hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the scale functionality of BigDecimal:

```
new BigDecimal(69.80000000001).setScale(1, RoundingMode.HALF_UP).doubleValue();
```

This is for further using the rounded value. If you just want to print the rounded value but hold the original, DecimalFormat is the right choice as described by Matt.

Comment: it give errors whn i apply it in my program. is there any header file required before doing this?????

Comment: What errors? Compiler? Do you have imported java.math.BigDecimal and java.math.RoundingMode? Any IDE should support this by "Organize Imports" or something like that.

Comment: no i havent imported any thing of such kind. anyways ill try it!